# nofitication created chrome extension api doesn't appear more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome Extension right now.

I'd like to show notification under certain condition.

and I'm able to show notification message once.

But, once the notification message appears, even though I reload a webpage, it doesn't show the notification message again!

I'm so stuck in this problem.

Please anyone help me out!!

thank in advance :)

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "test",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,

"permissions": [
    "tabs", "notifications", "http://*/*"
],

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*"],
        "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
]
```

}

**myscript.js**

```
var message = {
    text:"hello"
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, function(response) {

});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

var test = chrome.notifications.create(
    'notification',{   
        type: 'basic', 
        title: "title",
        message: request.text,
        iconUrl:"icon.png"
        },

    function(notificationId) {

    } 

);


chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function (notificationId, byUser){

        console.log("this doesn't call as well);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the notification is not clicked, it will automatically be hidden (but not closed) after a few seconds. Calling `create` again with an existing notification ID does not recreate or show the notification.

Call [`chrome.notifications.clear`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#method-clear) to remove the previously created notification with ID "notification" before calling `chrome.notifications.create`:.

```
var notificationId = 'notification'; // Whatever
chrome.notifications.clear(notificationId, function() {
    chrome.notifications.create(notificationId, ... );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I called clear() method within the callback for create() method.That's why it didn't work. Now I have clear() method outside of create() method, it finally works!!!